# Hamiltonian cycle in O(N)

Tags: algorithm, graph

I've been training with codility.com questions. There is a problem Eta 2011, which is trying to find the number of unique hamiltonian path.
You can read the whole problem [here](https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/eta2011/)

In summary. we have a graph, where each inner node is connected to exactly 3 other nodes, while outer nodes are connected to 1 inner node. We draw a path that passes through all outer nodes. Now all nodes(inner and outer) are connected to exactly 3 nodes. This is an undirected graph.

He would like to solve the problem in O(N)!!!
The solutions available solves the problem in O(2^N) or higher. There are also heuristic solutions but obviously they are not precise.
Using the knowledge that each node in the graph is connected to exactly three other nodes, is it possible to solve the hamiltonian path in O(N)?

Due to copyright I believe I'm not authorized to copy/paste the whole problem. but a link is provided in the first paragraph.

cheers
Moataz

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Complexity): `They remain NP-complete even for undirected planar graphs of maximum degree three`

Comment: You can post the question since it has a lot more information.

Comment: The actual problem is far more constrained than you describe.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei the question is copyrighted and theoretically I can't copy it

Comment: The range of values it can return is **very** limited and it's **much** simpler than having to calculate a hamiltonian path. I verified this - submitted a solution that got 100 out of 100.

Comment: @Dukeling How did you solve this without finding the hamiltonian paths?

Comment: I just suspected something and ran with it. I haven't been able to prove why it works so I can't really explain too well (with or without giving it away). Take any edge. Either it can be there, or it can't. What happens to the surrounding edges in each case? More specifically, how many possibilities are there in total for those edges? And each of the surrounding edges will affect their surrounding edges and those edges will affect their surrounding edges, etc. And then, um ... guess a value and see if it works on the given data.

Comment: @Dukeling It seems you can prove it by first taking a pair of edges from one or the "double endpoints".

Comment: @Dukeling what is your definition of "surrounding edges". I'm not sure I understood everything. Would you care to write 3-4 pseudocode lines to elaborate more your idea

Comment: @MoatazElmasry Surrounding / neighbouring edges are any edges that share a vertex / city. I don't really know how to elaborate on my idea. Seems [gustav](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16926542/1711796) has the right idea (though I don't quite understand).

Answer (score 4):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Complexity):

> ... They remain NP-complete even for undirected planar graphs of
>   maximum degree three

So, unless you have more information on the graph structure, all planar graphs of in-degree 3 is a subset of the possible input cases for this problem, and thus if you can solve this problem polynomially - you can also solve the problem for all planar graphs with in-degree 3  polynomially, and you can conclude [P=NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)

Comment: I updated the question a little. also please read the description here: https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/eta2011/

Comment: The structure of the graph given is much more special than an arbitrary graph with nodes of degree 3.

Comment: @amit: Yeah, but he is already basically handed the solution.

Answer (score 2):

`Hamiltonian cycle` is polynomial for certain subsets of graphs, e.g. [co-comparability graphs](http://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9290168A).

If your input graph is one of such graphs, you can solve the problem in polynomial time. Note that I am not stating that Hamiltonian cycle is not `NP-C`. All I am saying that it is polynomial for certain graphs.

Thus, if your input graph is a co-comparability graph, then you have a polynomial solution.

Comment: Interesting. I have to read this paper first and I'll come at you.thanks

Answer (score 2):

The graph is basically a tree with root node having 3 children and all other non-leaf nodes having 2 children. The leaves are connected from left to right.

You can think of each sub-tree as having two endpoint leaf nodes (say start and end).

Now given a subtree rooted at node n. If the hamiltonian route does not involve n and it's parent, then it will involve a path from the start to end and will cover all vertices of the sub-tree (in effect, a hamiltion route in the subtree routed at n).

Now consider the root of the tree. Suppose we take edges to x and y, with x being to left and y to the right.

Now we have to take the path from root to end point of subtree at x, and start point of subtree at y.

(A figure helps).

The rest of the path is completed by connect start to end of the subtrees which need paths to themselves.

This gives a recursive algorithm, and can be computed in O(n) time I believe.

Insane expectation of 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider a tree with the root and all the non-leaf nodes having two children.
The leaves are also connected from left to right, but the first leaf is **not** connected
to the last. How many paths are there **from the leftmost to the rightmost leaf**?

The answer is **only one**, and it's not hard to prove.

Now take the tree from the input. Pick any node and remove one of its edges.
You're left with two trees of the same structure as the one I mentioned at the beginning.
Using those two you can build exactly one Hamiltonian path.

Now the node you picked had three edges you could remove, hence there are **three ways** to 
make a Hamiltonian path in total :).

So the code boils down to checking for consistency and writing 3 in case everything is OK.
30 minutes is not that insane really.

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing this tree, what does this mean - `"the first node is not connected to the last"`?

Comment: You're right, I meant the first leaf, thanks. By removing an edge in the original tree you get two such trees (because two of the circle's edges you can remove as they have to be used anyway). I gave the problem to a friend though and she proved it by using incremental construction (start with one internal node and build from there), which is way more elegant.